# How to use -o with grep to extract a number

Tags: regex, grep, zsh

For example, if I try to run the command without the `-o` tag:

```
> grep '[0-9]*' <<< "ss1578130091522" 
> ss1578130091522
```

If I try to run with the `-o` tag, I get this:

```
> grep -o '[0-9]*' <<< "ss1578130091522" 
>
```

Why does it return me an empty line? Shouldn't it extract the number for me?

This is what I ideally want:

```
> grep -o '[0-9]*' <<< "ss1578130091522" 
> 1578130091522
```

This is using zsh on macOS Catalina.

Comment: Do you use GNU grep?

Comment: @Cyrus Probably the built-in MacOS / *BSD `grep` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `[0-9]*` matches the empty string, so that's what `grep -o` returns.

Try

```
grep -E -o '[0-9]+' <<<"ss1578130091522"
```

or

```
grep -o '[0-9]\+' <<<"ss1578130091522"
```

With `-E`, `grep` supports extended regular expression syntax.
Without `-E`, you have to use POSIX basic regular expression syntax, which
(insanely IMHO) requires the plus operator to be backslashed.
(The original `grep` from 1969 did not have this operator; that's why this syntax is "extended".)

You are clearly using `zsh`, not `bash`. These are two different, incompatible shells (though they share some features, and are both based on the Bourne shell `sh`).

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these work for me. The first one returns the exact same string (I need the number only), and the second one is weird, it puts me into this thing where it says `heredoc>` in the command line. I have to Ctrl+C to get out of it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `-o` option. Updated now.

Comment: The first one works like a charm! The second one still doesn't but that's alright

Comment: Works for me on Mojave, of course `zsh` is not the default shell here but it's available and I can reliably repro.

Comment: @tripleee : IMHO, your argument is not right. It is true that `[0-9]*` matches the empty string, but `*` is a greedy match. If the OP had `[0-9]*?`, I would agree with you. Indeed, trying `grep -E -o '[0-9]*' <<<"ss1578130091522"` returns me the full number.

Comment: @user1934428 I believe you are using GNU `grep` and observing it doing some DWIM stuff behind the scenes. Many other regex engines will happily and in some sense more predictably always retrieve the leftmost longest match.

Comment: @tripleee: I get the point! So it matches at the start of the string, and the leftmost longest match hence is the null string, as you said. Indeed I am using GNU grep, and it does return the number. The reason that grep behaves this way, seems to follow from the man page:  The `-o` prints _the non-empty parts of  a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line_. Indeed it would be odd, if for each match of `.*`, a separate (empty) line would be printed. So it is not exactly DWIM, but an effect of this particular option.